# Big Number Error Passing data to smart contract

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I have a smart contract function which receives an array of Structs as input. The struct is this.

```
struct Bgd {
        uint id;
        uint tanslationCode;
        string description;
        string image;
        string layer;
        uint supply;
        string createdBy;
        address revenue;
        uint price;
        bool approved;
    }
```

The function is below and simply takes the array of structs loops through and adds them to mappings.

```
mapping(uint => Bgd) _idToMetadata; 
mapping(uint => uint) _maxSupply; 
mapping(uint => uint) _itemsMinted;  
mapping(uint => bool) _approved;  

function addAttachedBackgrounds(Bgd[] calldata bgds)external onlyRole(UPDATER_ROLE){
        for (uint i; i < bgds.length; i++){
            uint id = bgds[i].id;
            _idToMetadata[id] = bgds[i];
            uint s = bgds[i].supply;
            _maxSupply[id] = s;//bgds[i].supply;
            if (id > bgdCurrentid){
                bgdCurrentid = id + 1; 
            }
            _approved[id] = true;
        }
    }
```

I am now running some unit tests with Hardhat and ethers. But I get an error when I try to add data to this function.

```
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.2)
```

The code I use to create the input array is as follows.

```
let bgdData = [];
const accessories = require("./accessories.json");
  for (i = 0; i < accessories.length; i++) {
    let a = accessories[i];
    let a_price = Number(a["price"]).toFixed(4);
    let weiPrice = ethers.utils.parseEther(a_price);
 
    a["price"] = weiPrice;
    a["revenue"] = "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266";
    if (a["layer"] == "background") {
      bgdData.push(a);
      // console.log(a);
    } else {
      a["avType"] = 1;
      a["city"] = 1;
      accessoryData.push(a);
    }
  }
```

Then to add it to the contract.

```
const addBgsData = async () => {
    await bgDataContract.addAttachedBackgrounds(bgdData);
  };
```

The other array created in the same way works fine.
When I console log the array of bgdData is get the following objects.

```
{
    id: 6,
    translationCode: 6,
    description: '',
    image: 'https://avatarimg.metropolisworld.net/img/accessories/1/none/6',
    layer: 'background',
    supply: 10,
    createdBy: 'Puks',
    revenue: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
    price: BigNumber { value: "3255100000000000000" },
    approved: true
  }
```

So my question is why am I getting this error? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when the wrong type of data is passed as an argument.

I guess in your case, an `undefined` value is passed in the struct.

Also on a side note, while calling smart contract methods, if the number is long, consider passing it as a `string`.
i.e. Your updated `bgdData` object may look something like the below:

```
{
    id: 6,
    translationCode: 6,
    description: '',
    image: 'https://avatarimg.metropolisworld.net/img/accessories/1/none/6',
    layer: 'background',
    supply: 10,
    createdBy: 'Puks',
    revenue: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
    price: "3255100000000000000",
    approved: true
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried as a string but I still get the same error.

Comment: Try checking the values, so that correct values are passed and no `undefined` is being passed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a spelling error in the struct which was causing the issue.